# .NET Core Microservice using RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, microservices, rawrabbit

I am planing to use Microservice architecture for a project. The selected technology stack is `.NET Core` with `Docker` and `RabbitMQ` as a simple service bus and this should be able to deploy on `Linux`.

Lets say I have a `Payment` service and an `Order` Service, I want each of these services to expose `REST` endpoints. Because of that, I thought of making these two services as `.NET Core Web APIs`.

But the problem is the inter-service communication using `RabbitMQ`. Whenever I get a new `order`, I want to publish an event using `RabbitMQ` and then listen to that event in `Payment` service to perform certain operations (database updates). But since these are `Web APIs`, I don't think it's possible to listen to events as I described. (I feel like I might have to use something like a console application to subscribe to events.)

I would like to find the most viable method to achieve this using the best practices considering the scalability and extendability of the system.

Comment: ASP.NET Core applications are console application. You can simply create an object that will listen to messages at application startup along with WebAPI registration..

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov, Thank you for the response. Could you please explain a bit your suggestion?

Answer (score 11):

When you create your application with .NET Core you bootstrap things in `Main` method and then register services and middle-ware in `Startup` class. So before you start web host you can also create and start your messaging services:

```
public class MessageListener
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // Listen to rabbit QM and all the things.
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Listen to messages.
    var messaging =  MessageListener();
    messaging.Start();

    // Configure web host and start it.
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        ...
        .Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 `IHostedService` interface was introduced to achieve same goal and they mention this scenario in their [announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/08/25/asp-net-core-2-0-features-1/). Here is [an example](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-2-ihostedservice) of how to implement one.

Comment: So what you are saying is, even in a .NET Core Web API project, I can simply register my listeners to handle event that will be published by other services?

Comment: Yup, exactly that. If the logic of the subdomain is implemented in a service it does not matter how commands are send: through web api or through message queue.

Comment: Thanks, do you think it's a good idea to handle it like this? will there be any drawbacks?

Comment: That's how I do it in my projects. The idea of microservice is to implemented a Bounded Context (a subdomain or part of it). It should have a domain model inside, which can be accessed either from web api controllers or from message handlers.

Comment: @PIKP, please check the updated if that's still relevant for you.